Proxmox Server pve-root full
I have a Proxmox Server with an 2tb main drive where VMs are stored and a 1tb backup drive. On the 2tb drive 100G are a partition for pve-root.
A few days ago the 100G suddenly filled up completely. I dont find the cause, would appreciate any help.
As you can see the 1tb backup drive a mounted at /home/backups.
No other directorys contain any big files, no logs, no isos, no backups just a few container templates but nothing concerning.
If anyone has any followup question i'm happy to provide you with any outputs.
Thanks
root@pve:/var/log# df -h
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                   15G     0   15G   0% /dev
tmpfs                 2.9G  1.5M  2.9G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/pve-root   94G   89G  752M 100% /
tmpfs                  15G   72M   15G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                 5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
efivarfs              128K   14K  110K  11% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
/dev/nvme0n1p2       1022M  344K 1022M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/sda              916G  729G  141G  84% /home/backups
/dev/fuse             128M   52K  128M   1% /etc/pve
tmpfs                 2.9G     0  2.9G   0% /run/user/0

root@pve:/var/log# lsblk
NAME                         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
sda                            8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk /home/backups
nvme0n1                      259:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
|-nvme0n1p1                  259:1    0  1007K  0 part 
|-nvme0n1p2                  259:2    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
`-nvme0n1p3                  259:3    0   1.8T  0 part 
  |-pve-swap                 252:0    0     8G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  |-pve-root                 252:1    0    96G  0 lvm  /
  |-pve-data_tmeta           252:2    0   9.1G  0 lvm  
  | `-pve-data-tpool         252:4    0   1.7T  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-data             252:5    0   1.7T  1 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--100--disk--0 252:6    0    64G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--101--disk--0 252:7    0    64G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--102--disk--0 252:8    0   200G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--103--disk--0 252:9    0   100G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--104--disk--0 252:10   0     4M  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--104--disk--2 252:11   0    32G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--107--disk--0 252:12   0    16G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--106--disk--0 252:13   0   800G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--108--disk--0 252:14   0    40G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--109--disk--0 252:15   0    32G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--110--disk--0 252:16   0   100G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--111--disk--0 252:17   0    64G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--112--disk--0 252:18   0    40G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--113--disk--0 252:19   0    40G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--105--disk--0 252:20   0    50G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--114--disk--0 252:21   0    10G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--115--disk--0 252:22   0    70G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--116--disk--0 252:23   0    50G  0 lvm  
  |   |-pve-vm--117--disk--0 252:24   0    70G  0 lvm  
  |   `-pve-vm--118--disk--0 252:25   0    15G  0 lvm  
  `-pve-data_tdata           252:3    0   1.7T  0 lvm  
    `-pve-data-tpool         252:4    0   1.7T  0 lvm  
      |-pve-data             252:5    0   1.7T  1 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--100--disk--0 252:6    0    64G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--101--disk--0 252:7    0    64G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--102--disk--0 252:8    0   200G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--103--disk--0 252:9    0   100G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--104--disk--0 252:10   0     4M  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--104--disk--2 252:11   0    32G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--107--disk--0 252:12   0    16G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--106--disk--0 252:13   0   800G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--108--disk--0 252:14   0    40G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--109--disk--0 252:15   0    32G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--110--disk--0 252:16   0   100G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--111--disk--0 252:17   0    64G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--112--disk--0 252:18   0    40G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--113--disk--0 252:19   0    40G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--105--disk--0 252:20   0    50G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--114--disk--0 252:21   0    10G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--115--disk--0 252:22   0    70G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--116--disk--0 252:23   0    50G  0 lvm  
      |-pve-vm--117--disk--0 252:24   0    70G  0 lvm  
      `-pve-vm--118--disk--0 252:25   0    15G  0 lvm

    ```
    

--- / ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
728.7 GiB [##################################] /home
3.8 GiB [                                  ] /usr
.   2.0 GiB [                                  ] /var
332.9 MiB [                                  ] /boot
72.0 MiB [                                  ] /dev
6.2 MiB [                                  ] /etc
1.5 MiB [                                  ] /run
172.0 KiB [                                  ] /root
64.0 KiB [                                  ] /tmp
e  16.0 KiB [                                  ] /lost+found
8.0 KiB [                                  ] /mnt
e   4.0 KiB [                                  ] /srv
e   4.0 KiB [                                  ] /opt
e   4.0 KiB [                                  ] /media
.   0.0   B [                                  ] /proc
0.0   B [                                  ] /sys
@   0.0   B [                                  ]  libx32
@   0.0   B [                                  ]  lib64
@   0.0   B [                                  ]  lib32
@   0.0   B [                                  ]  sbin
@   0.0   B [                                  ]  lib
@   0.0   B [                                  ]  bin
    


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/9nkyjENK.png

SOLVED

under the mountpoint /home/backups were large files which cant be seen by any scans.
Solution:
umount /home/backups
Delete files in home/backups
mount /home/backups


Please put your solution in an answer, then come back later and accept it (click the ✔ sign).
